# Is it possible to create a Uri that is not absolute?

Tags: c#, .net, uri

I am curious about the Uri property:

```
public bool IsAbsoluteUri { get; }
```

Is it ever possible for it to be false? It doesn't seem that I can create a Uri that is not absolute. The latter (uriTwo) throws:

```
var uriOne = new Uri( "http://stackoverflow.com/about" );
var uriTwo = new Uri( "/about" );
```

Same seems to be true with the builder. What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.  Try the following

```
var uri = new Uri("foo.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
Console.WriteLine(uri.IsAbsoluteUri); // prints false
```

Comment: @TrueWill yes. it absolutely is not absolute

Answer (score 2):

You need to use another constructor that takes a [`UriKind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind.aspx), [for instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131565.aspx). The constructor that takes just a path assumes absolute kind.